# All fields that are required should not be required if specific field is changed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 4 fields

```
"name" => "required",
"parent_id" => "",
"url" => "required",
"url_id" => "required",
```

The fields name, url and url_id should be required
But now i wan't to change only the parent_id and i don't want to change the name url and url_id so i dont change these.

I want the 3 fields that are required not too be required if i only change the parent_id

Edit:
in my frontend there are 2 ways to update these 4 fields,

1. is in a form where i can change all the required fields.
2. is where i only want to change the parent_id but then i get into the error that name url and url_id are required when i want to update

Comment: You are going to have to give us a bit more context to your question. As it stands this is Unclear and/or Too Broad

Comment: THen show us the frontend code please

Comment: Is it more clear want i want now? I cant explain it in any better way

Comment: The frontend isn't there because the backend isn't working yet. I need something like an required_if on each of these required fields where it says that if i change the parent_id those 3 fields are not required anymore

Comment: So how do you build this data structure and how do you use it

Comment: Also, are you using a framework?

Comment: I use Laravel forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you get these values from a form so you can store this field before applying `required` to other fields

if `parent_id` has a value return nothing but if it's empty return `required`

`$condition = $_POST('parent_id') ? "" : "required"`

then

```
"name" => $condition ,
"url" => $condition ,
"url_id" => $condition ,
```

Hope that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Despite selected answer could work as expected, it's not the prettier solution.
You can use the validation rule provided by laravel `required_without`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-without

So if you want those fields to be required when `parent_id` is not present you can simply do:

```php
"name" => "required_without:parent_id",
"parent_id" => "",
"url" => "required_without:parent_id",
"url_id" => "required_without:parent_id",
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are no conditionally required in MySQL however what you can do is to set default values to required fields so that when you do not what to set them the default values got set by default.

```
ALTER TABLE x MODIFY COLUMN col NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]';
```

Another option is to rollback required field so that it can be null.

```
ALTER TABLE x MODIFY COLUMN col NULL;
```